# Groupby streak of numbers and a mask

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is my pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 1, 55, 66, 333, 444, 1, 2, 10], 'b': [1,1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1]})
```

And this is the way that I need it after using `groupby`. I want all of 1s in b and two -1 after the streak of 1s. For example the first group is all of the consecutive 1s and then after the streak ends I want two -1s. If the streak of -1 is less than two, just gives the first -1 which is group two in the example:

```
     a  b
0   10  1
1   20  1
2    1  1
3   55 -1
4   66 -1

     a  b
7    1  1
8    2  1
9   10 -1
```

I know that I need a mask. I have tried some of them but didn't work. These are some of my tries:

```
df.groupby(df.b.diff().cumsum().eq(1))
df.groupby(df['b'].ne(df['b'].shift()).cumsum())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear.

Assuming you want to reset the group when "b" shifts from -1 to 1. And let's add a condition on "a" for the demo:

```
# restart group on -1 -> 1
group = df['b'].diff().gt(0).cumsum()
# drop rows with a≥100
m = df['a'].lt(100)

for k,g in df[m].groupby(group):
    print(g)
```

Output:

```
    a  b
0  10  1
1  20  1
2   1  1
3  55 -1
4  66 -1
    a  b
7   1  1
8   2  1
9  10 -1
```

##### update

```
m = df['b'].eq(1)
group = (m&m.ne(m.shift())).cumsum()
n = m.groupby(group).sum()

df.groupby(group, group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.head(n[g.name]+2))
```

Output:

```
    a  b
0  10  1
1  20  1
2   1  1
3  55 -1
4  66 -1
7   1  1
8   2  1
9  10 -1
```

as a for loop:

```
m = df['b'].eq(1)
group = (m&m.ne(m.shift())).cumsum()
n = m.groupby(group).sum()

for k, g in df.groupby(group, group_keys=False):
    print(k)
    print(g.head(n[k]+2))
```

Output:

```
1
    a  b
0  10  1
1  20  1
2   1  1
3  55 -1
4  66 -1
2
    a  b
7   1  1
8   2  1
9  10 -1
```

Comment: @Amir this is producing two groups, but then merging. See the update for how to use it in a loop

Comment: @Amir for some reason my edit didn't go through, check again